# Shoud I require a mongoose model or get it from mongoose directly

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a model in a file `models/Model.js` like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const modelSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String })
const Model = mongoose.model('Model', modelSchema)
module.exports = Model
```

Then when I use it I import it like any other module:

```
const Model = require('../models/Model')
```

My question is: If every time I `require` a module the code is executed (in this case it would "run" `Model.js` every time I import it), would it be more efficient (or at least make more sense) to import it like this?:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Model = mongoose.model('Model')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question contains an incorrect assumption:

> If every time I require a module the code is executed (in this case it
>   would "run" Model.js every time I import it)...

The code in Model.js is only run the first time `require` is called to load that module. The resulting module object is then placed in [`require.cache`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache) and subsequent `require` calls for that same module simply return the same module object from the cache.

So there's no meaningful performance difference between the two approaches and it's up to your personal preference.

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't know about modules cache, thanks!